# PHP: Insert variable into DOM structure where < tag item="#" /> is found

Tags: php, dom

I have two php variables: 
1) `$item1 = "baking";` 2) `$item2 = "fun"`;

These variables need to be inserted into the DOM structure below.

```
<random>
      <li>
          I also think <star item="1"/> can be <star item="2"/> sometimes.
      </li>
  </random>
```

I use the following code to get the '`li`' elements.

```
$elements = $dom->getElementsByTagName('li');

foreach ($elements as $node) {

  $sentence = $node->nodeValue;
// This will currently print "I also think can be sometimes."
}
```

**How can I insert `baking` into where `<star item="1"/>` is and `fun` into where `<star item="2"/>` is, so that the end result is:**

```
I also think baking can be fun sometimes.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a quick implementation mate, adjust it for your needs:

```
<?php
$xml = <<< XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<random>
      <li>
          I also think <star item="1"/> can be <star item="2"/> sometimes.
      </li>
  </random>
XML;

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadXML($xml);
$liElements = $dom->getElementsByTagName('li');

$starElements = $dom->getElementsByTagName('star');
$i = $starElements->length - 1; 
while ($i > -1) { 
$starElement = $starElements->item($i);
            if ( $starElement->nodeName == 'star' ) {
                if ($starElement->getAttribute('item') == 1) {
                 $newelement = $dom->createTextNode('baking'); 
                 $starElement->parentNode->replaceChild($newelement, $starElement);
                } else if ($starElement->getAttribute('item') == 2) {
                 $newelement = $dom->createTextNode('fun'); 
                 $starElement->parentNode->replaceChild($newelement, $starElement);
                }
            }
        $i--;
    }

foreach ($liElements as $node) {
  echo $node->nodeValue;
}
?>
```

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/4aa46eb297f49ea4f2302ac265c0dd805925b657